# Remove objects, leaving only the stroke and the drop shadow (illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, shadows, drop-shadow

Just found this site! Seems pretty awesome. Im wondering if anyone knows how to achieve this effect:

I want to remove the white objects (text) from the image, but keep the stroke and the drop shadow.

[image]

When I try to make the fill transparent, this is what happens:

[image]

Any help would be super appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Transparency Knockout Group

When you define a transparency knockout group, the elements within that group don't show through eachother, exactly like you want.

- Group everything including the shadow
- Transparency panel → Check **Knockout Group** (you may need to click twice)

[image]

- Select everything with a white fill
- Appearance panel → Fill → Opacity 0% (don't set the fill color to none):

[image]

You can read more about transparency knockout groups here:

- [**Illustrator Help / Create a transparency knockout group**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transparency-blending-modes.html#create_a_transparency_knockout_group)