# Making transparent but still hiding any objects below in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, transparency

Hello I am new to Illustrator (I was working with photoshop a few years). How can I fix this problem?

[image: this is what i have]

[image: this is how it should be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. Manually cut the paths, probably using the Scissors Tool (<kbd>C</kbd>).
2. Use pathfinder operations (**Window → Pathfinder**).

or

3. Define a [transparency knockout group](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/73385/52050).