# Illustrator: how to make shapes opaque with no fill?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, transparency

I have shapes overlapping that have no fill (because I am designing a t-shirt and just want the shirt color to show underneath the shapes' lines) but I still want a shape on top to cover the lines underneath it?

I've attached a screenshot; I want the banner to still show the gray of the t-shirt underneath it but want it on top of the circle without the circle's lines crossing it.

Thanks in advance for the help!
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making transparent but still hiding any objects below in Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74472/making-transparent-but-still-hiding-any-objects-below-in-illustrator)

Comment: Sounds like you might want to make the circle a clipping path. It's a little unclear. You can break vector lines at endpoints and delete segments. Are you looking for an automatic way of altering the design, like the pathfinder tool, or are you wondering how to edit vector segments? There is no "color" or fill you can add if you want to make the ribbon look solid but still see through it,

Answer (score 1):

Filled shapes can be piled to the wanted order. Unfilled shapes must be cut or fill temporarily + merge.

Before you start, be sure that "Smart quides" and "Snap to points" are on. "Snap to grid" must be off.

[image]

Make a group as soon as you are ready to keep the parts together.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to approach this:

1. Non destructive: create a clipping mask - it will show objects that are only in mask region. Just make a big square shape and cut out a shape that should hide your lines. Then select your masking shape (should be on top of the one you need to cover) and your element that is supposed to be partially hidden and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (Object → Clipping mask → Make). Your clipping mask is ready.
   [Article explaining clipping masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html)
2. Destructive: simply cut out all of the parts you do not want to be seen.